# HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway when pushing to bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, push, bitbucket

I have a mercurial repository, when I try to push my changes  to bitbucket I suddenly get the error

```
HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
```

after a long moment of wait (searching changes..)

Any idea? this has had me stumped for two days!

Comment: Are other commands like `hg incoming` and `hg pull` working correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people report similar issues when trying to push big changesets using the HTTP protocol. Try using SSH instead. You can find instructions for Bitbucket [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html).

Comment: I changed my .hg/hgrc with `ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame/` but I got this  remote: `Permission denied (publickey).
abandon : no suitable response from remote hg !
`

Comment: Did you configure your public key in Bitbucket ?

Comment: How do I do that? excuse me I'm new to all this

Comment: That link is dead...it would be nice to duplicate the instructions or update the link.

Comment: @user Thanks for the heads-up, I've updated the link.

Comment: That link says you have to enable compression. **Don't** do that. It'll simply not work and to say the error messages are misguiding is an understatement.